Closing Chrome browser does not fire pagehide
When a user closes chrome while logged in to my system, I want to save some stats in our db as if they had properly used the sign out link. I have it working when the user navigates away, or when the user closes ONE the tab of multiple open tabs but not when the user closes the entire browser. What am I missing?
I added a onpagehide event handler that uses navigator.sendBeacon to update my db.
When the user navigates away, or when the user closes ONE the tab of multiple open tabs, the event handler fires and updates the db.
But when the user closes the entire browser, the event does not fire so the db is not updated.
window.addEventListener('pagehide', function() {ProcessLogout();});


From MDN: "The pagehide event is sent to a Window when the browser hides the current page in the process of presenting a different page from the session's history." Why should that fire when the browser is closed, it's not showing a different page.

I see that, thank you. Many others advised using pagehide instead of unload or beforeunload. Can you please suggest another event I could use?

I'm not sure there's any good event for this. JS is very restrictive about what you can do in any of these situations, because malware has abused them to prevent closing the browser or navigating away from the bad page.

I would recommend trying the visibilitychange event instead of 'pagehide' and designing your stats update to handle that it may not be the final thing and may have a subsequent call where you would update the stats again (for example, a user may have just minimized the window, then raised it again, then closed it - that would generate 3 visibilitychange events: hidden, shown, then hidden again).
